# ObjectMapper is converting to wrong datetime

Tags: java, datetime

I am passing date as `"scoreTimestamp": "2015-04-15T10:00:00.000Z",`
And want to save this json as string in database so using method

```
 ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String ratingData = objMapper.writeValueAsString(scoreTimestamp);
```

I want date to be as:   "scoreTimestamp":"2015-04-15 10:00", where as objectMapper is converting this to :

```
  "scoreTimestamp" : {
"year" : 2015,
"dayOfMonth" : 15,
"dayOfWeek" : 3,
"era" : 1,
"dayOfYear" : 105,
"monthOfYear" : 4,
"weekyear" : 2015,
"yearOfEra" : 2015,
"yearOfCentury" : 15,
"weekOfWeekyear" : 16,
"centuryOfEra" : 20,
"millisOfSecond" : 0,
"millisOfDay" : 36000000,
"secondOfMinute" : 0,
"secondOfDay" : 36000,
"minuteOfHour" : 0,
"minuteOfDay" : 600,
"hourOfDay" : 10,
"zone" : {
  "fixed" : true,
  "id" : "UTC"
},
```

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Please see the answer(s) mentioned in the article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41876037/jackson-date-format-for-offsetdatetime-in-spring-boot

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since Jackson v2.0, you can use @JsonFormat annotation directly on fields:

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", timezone="GMT")
private Date scoreTimestamp;
```

or make it default

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a z");
objMapper.setDateFormat(df);
```

Comment: Its not working..its still same 
  "scoreTimestamp": {
        "year": 2015,
        "dayOfMonth": 15,
        "dayOfWeek": 3,
        "era": 1,
        "dayOfYear": 105,
        "millisOfSecond": 0,
        "millisOfDay": 36000000,
        "secondOfMinute": 0,
        "secondOfDay": 36000,
        "minuteOfHour": 0,
        "minuteOfDay": 600,
        "hourOfDay": 10,
        "monthOfYear": 4,
        "weekyear": 2015,
        "yearOfEra": 2015,
        "weekOfWeekyear": 16,
        "yearOfCentury": 15,
     ......etc

Comment: Not working for me either. I have the `DateTime` objects in a `Map` inside the object to serialise.