# Jackson date-format for OffsetDateTime in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I'm trying to output an OffsetDateTime from my Spring application, and have in my application.properties these properties:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false
spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm
```

However when the date is returned it is formatted as

```
"2017-01-30T16:55:00Z"
```

How should I correctly configure the format for the date in my Spring application?

Comment: Which spring boot version is that?

Comment: This was with 1.5.6

Comment: 'date-format' is only for java.util.Date objects.

Comment: In Spring Boot, "spring.jackson.date-format" in global config (application.properties) is only for java.util.Date, and not for any java.time.* object. For more detail, refer to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9004

Answer (score 31, accepted):

So I've managed to figure out a solution, but if you have an alternative please post it.

I ended up creating a new primary `ObjectMapper` bean, and registering a new module with a custom serializer for `OffsetDateTime`. I'm able to set my own date format in here, using `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`. I also had to register the `JavaTimeModule` with my mapper.

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonOffsetDateTimeMapper{

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
        simpleModule.addSerializer(OffsetDateTime.class, new JsonSerializer<OffsetDateTime>() {
            @Override
            public void serialize(OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
                jsonGenerator.writeString(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.format(offsetDateTime));
            }
        });
        objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);

        return objectMapper;
    }

}
```

Comment: For my case, all I needed was `.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())` on my ObjectMapper

Comment: For my case too, just add .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()) on my ObjectMapper before my objectMapper.readValue(...)

Comment: can you translate it into kotlin please?

Answer (score 30):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
```

By doing that, you can get OffsetDateTime properties as ISO 8601 including offset in your target.

Comment: Although the accepted answer worked, this also works for me and is much more concise. Of note, I'm just using Jackson in an AWS Lambda, so it's not in Spring and doesn't have any of the framework/Beans/auto-config/etc.

Answer (score 7):

Adding a dependency on jackson-modules-java8 worked for me (jackson-datatype-jsr310 is deprecated)

```
<!-- deserialize Java 8 date time types e.g OffsetDateTime --> 
<dependency> 
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-modules-java8</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I also needed to add this for it to work:

```
 om.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

No need for the write-dates-as-timestamps=false or om.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS) - that is applicable for Java "Date" object.

I used this annotation:

```
 @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
```

and get output like this:

**"timestamp":"2020-04-23T08:00:00.000-06:00"**

Comment: You didn't actually need to register the module manually like that; you just needed to add a JavaTimeModule bean to your application context and boot would have done it for you: `Any beans of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module are automatically registered with the auto-configured Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder and are applied to any ObjectMapper instances that it creates. This provides a global mechanism for contributing custom modules when you add new features to your application.`

Comment: `Note that as of 2.6, this module does NOT support auto-registration, because of existence of legacy version, JSR310Module. Legacy version has the same functionality, but slightly different default configuration: see JSR310Module for details.`

Comment: Also you still need to disable `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS`

Answer (score 4):

1. Add jackson-datatype-jsr310 to your dependencies
2. Add to application.properties:

   ```
   spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false
   ```

You will get:

```
"lastUpdated": "2017-07-16T19:17:57.689Z"
```

Comment: Does not work in a MockMVC controller test with spring boot 2.0.0.M7

Answer (score 3):

The spring property doesn't work for me as well. Setting the property to `ObjectMapper` works for me though.

```
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried put `@JsonFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z")` before your field?

```
@JsonProperty("timestamp")
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
private OffsetDateTime timestamp;
```

I guess you will get:

```
2017-01-30'T'16:55
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing `@EnableWebMvc` and just inheriting from `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` helped me not to overwrite the ObjectMapper config, so that the configuration properties specified in the `application.yml` are applied.

Comment: This was the issue also on my side. Thanks @adlerer

Answer (score 0):

I did this using a [Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer.html)

```java
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSxxx");

    JsonSerializer<Temporal> temporalSerializer = new JsonSerializer<>() {
        @Override
        public void serialize(Temporal dateTime, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
            jsonGenerator.writeString(formatter.format(dateTime));
        }
    };
    return builder -> builder
            .serializerByType(ZonedDateTime.class, temporalSerializer)
            .serializerByType(OffsetDateTime.class, temporalSerializer);
}
```