# Formatting Java Time with Spring Boot using JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I want to implement a custom validator in a Spring Boot v1.5.14.RELEASE app. First I create a custom constraint annotation:

I have this object:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@SuperBuilder
public class Hotel {

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private OffsetDateTime interactionDurationStart;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private OffsetDateTime interactionDurationEnd;

}
```

in the yml:

```
spring:
  jackson:
    mapper:
      DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION: true
    serialization:
      WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS: false
```

and in my configuration file:

```
@Primary
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    //objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
    simpleModule.addSerializer(OffsetDateTime.class, new JsonSerializer<OffsetDateTime>() {
        @Override
        public void serialize(OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            jsonGenerator.writeString(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.format(offsetDateTime));
        }
    });
    objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);

    return objectMapper;
}
```

but this is what i see in the API response

```
"interactionDurationEnd" : {
      "offset" : {
        "totalSeconds" : 7200,
        "id" : "+02:00",
        "rules" : {
          "transitionRules" : [ ],
          "transitions" : [ ],
          "fixedOffset" : true
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Spring MVC* uses *Jackson* as default json object mapper. *Jackson* doesn't support serialization/deserialization for java8's Time API by default, but it provides a module for integrating it. Just include this dependency in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

*Spring Boot* auto-configuration will detect the *Jackson* module class `JavaTimeModule` and will added it to the `ObjectMapper` instance.

If you're creating the `ObjectMapper` instance by hand, you can add the module using this line:

```
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

Comment: It’s not my home field, but I was under the impression that jackson-datatype-jsr310 was merged into [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8), and that you should nowadays prefer to use the latter.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the ObjectMapper that spring uses recognize only Date by default. Have a look at this [Jackson date-format for OffsetDateTime in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41876037/jackson-date-format-for-offsetdatetime-in-spring-boot) if you want to use OffsetDateTime field as you will need to register a serializer / deserialize to do the job for you.

If you want to change the field type to Date then I am not sure if JsonFormat will work as I have never used it. My solution to the case is providing an ObjectMapper bean to spring with `objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"))` which does the trick.

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

what version of jackson-databind ?

try adding the Shape

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

if it work then that your problem there was a bug with old version jackson-bind that required shape to be use or by default it will be any.