# Spring Boot Rest - OffsetDateTime Returned as Float

Tags: json, spring-boot, rest, serialization, jackson

I have a Spring Boot application (2.4.1), where an `OffsetDateTime` field is returned as float value from `RestController`. Example:

```
"created_at": 1616080724.531610100
```

I tried all the suggested solutions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41876037/jackson-date-format-for-offsetdatetime-in-spring-boot). None of them worked for me.

I also tried to add a very simple end-point that only returns `OffsetDateTime`:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public OffsetDateTime test() {
    return OffsetDateTime.now();
}
```

The result is the same, it's returned as float value.

Then I tried the same end-point in a minimal Spring Boot project and it's returned in ISO format as expected:

```
"2021-03-18T15:39:14.5295632+01:00"
```

This all points to some transitive dependency messing up with the default Jackson serializers used by Sprint Boot. But `mvn dependency:tree` doesn't give me any suspicious dependencies (e.g. no gson marshaller dependency).

I also tried enabling TRACE logging, and I can see that the object written in `HttpEntityMethodProcessor` has the correctly formatted `created_at` time:

```
TRACE org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Writing [class MyObject {
....
createdAt: 2021-03-18T16:37:34.113316500+01:00
...
```

But it still ends up as float on the client side (testing on browser and with Postman). What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some debugging in Jackson classes, I found out that `InstantSerializerBase#serialize` method was being called with the default `SerializerProvider` (`DefaultSerializerProviderImpl`), which had the `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` feature enabled. That resulted in serializing `OffsetDateTime` values as epoch seconds + nanos.

I was able to fix the problem by adapting our `WebMvcConfigurer` implementation as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    // Some other configuration

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper()));
    }

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper()
            .disable(WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    }
}
```

After this change, `OffsetDateTime` fields are finally serialized in ISO format; e.g.

```
"created_at": "2021-03-19T17:05:27.785646+01:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Soution with `configureMessageConverters` is exacty what I needed. I have the same problem and you really helped me. Thanks!

Maybe you should report the solution to Spring