Unable to make field private final java.time.ZoneOffset java.time.OffsetDateTime.offset accessible:
I have this in the frontend, timestamp the most important, as Date
export interface MessageModel {
    id?: String;
    senderId: String;
    receiverId: String;
    content: String;
    timestamp: Date;
    seen: boolean;
}

in the backend, i have this
    @Column(name = "timestamp", nullable = false)
    private OffsetDateTime timestamp;

and this is the dto
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")  // Handles date with timezone
    private OffsetDateTime timestamp;

I also added, reading a bunch of solutions here this in application.properties
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false
but somehow, i still get this error
Unable to make field private final java.time.ZoneOffset java.time.OffsetDateTime.offset accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.time" to unnamed module @61862a7f
i tried a lot of solutions but none of them worked

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70144165/java-17-java-lang-reflect-inaccessibleobjectexception-unable-to-make-field-priv
