# LocalDateTime in swagger always defaults to 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH-mm-ss.ssZ' format

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have a java POJO which has a LocalDateTime property.
The generated swagger always generates in "2016-01-08T22:34:22.337Z" format, but I don't need that format. Below is what I am trying in the POJO.

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = DATE_TIME_FORMAT)
private LocalDateTime dateTime;
```

I have noticed the @JsonFormat is not working at all, even if I remove that, its still defaulting to the above format.

I have even tried with :

```
@ApiModelProperty(required = true,example = "2016-01-01T09-10-50.ssZ")
```

Even that is not working.

Comment: A `LocalDateTime` does not have an offset or a zone, but the swagger datetime contains a `Z` at the end, which means the time is taken in UTC / +00:00. Can you change it to an `OffsetDateTime`? You can format that as desired…

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is not a format, it's a date with certain properties. I think you're also running into issues with the Open Api Spec on dates: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49379235/995891

Comment: @deHaar After changing it to OffsetDateTime how do I format that, Using @JsonFormat?

Comment: Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41876037/jackson-date-format-for-offsetdatetime-in-spring-boot) for example…